# WCF Service Datacontract got replaced with OperationContract name

Tags: wcf, datacontract, operation-contract

After adding my wcf to website data contract got replaced with operation contract. How to get back like code 2

code1

```
[OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IDocument/GetFile", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IDocument/GetFileResponse")] 
            [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)] 
            GetFileResponse GetFile(GetFileRequest request);
```

code2

```
 [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IDocument/GetFile", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IDocument/GetFileResponse")]
        AppFile GetFile(AppFile objFile);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by DataContract?  There's nothing in either code snippet related to DataContracts.

Comment: AppFile in code 2 is my data contract, usually when i inherit my web service i get code like code 2, but in one application AppFile is getting replaced with GetFileResponse